# How do I print back specific data from a list using user input?

Tags: python-3.x

In summary I'm trying to create a password manager. The Idea is that the program would ask the user input.
If user writes "new", the program asks input on the website, username and password and then store this data in a text file in the form of a List.

Now the main problem:

I want to be able to access selected data and have the program print said data from the text file to me.
For example:
I input into the program the website "google" along with username: "potato" and password: "potato"

After that, the program asks me what else I want to do. And if I write "access google", I want to program to give me back the website, username and password that are SPECIFIC to the google input.

This is necessary, as I will be adding several different inputs.

I have no idea how to do this and have no tutor. I hope someone can give a solution I can learn from.

Below you will find the base code I have come up with.

Keep in mind that I am a beginner. Thank you.

```
vault = open("Passvault.txt", "r+")
list = []
action = input("What do you want to do? ")


def tit():
    global title
    title = input("Add website: ")
    return title


def user():
    global username
    username = input("Create username: ")
    return username


def passw():
    global password
    password = input("Create password: ")
    return password

running = True
while running:
    creation = True
    tit()
    user()
    passw()
    if action == "new":
        tit()
        user()
        passw()
        #I added a class here hoping that i could create a class with an argument referencing the title
        #so that when i type access "title" in the next if statement it would print back the data
        #relevant to the selected title
        class new(str(title)):
            list.append(tit)
            list.append(user)
            list.append(passw)


        vault.close()

    if action == "access" + title:
        creation = False
        print(title)
        print("Username: " + username)
        print("Password: " + password)
        vault.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code. This code stores the username, password, and website name in the txt file and also prints the username and password w.r.t website name.

```
    import re # used to search patterns.
    file_name = 'Passvault.txt'
    while True:
        action = input("What do you want to do? ")
        if action == 'new':
            title = input("Add website: ")
            username = input("Create username:")
            password = input('Create password')
            #writing data into the file
            with open (file_name,'a') as f:
                data = f.write(f'{title} {username} {password}\n')  

        if 'access' in action:#if input contains access word
            website = action.split()[1].strip() #storing website name which is written after access
            #reading the data 
            with open(file_name,'r') as f:
                data = f.read()
            #searching for all username password related to website
            username_pass = re.findall(f'{website}\s+(.*?)\n',data,re.S)#example google sachin 1234
            print('Website: ',website)
            print('Username, Password',username_pass)
```

Comment: Could you explain your code please? It's one thing if it works but I'd also like to understand it.
Like what does the "as f" do?
or the re module?

Comment: Also it doesn't work properly.
It only prints back the latest title username and password input.
If you input 2 websites, usernames and passwords, It won't print out the first, only the second.

Comment: I have updated the code with comments. Now it will work properly for multiple websites. You can study more about re module here https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html
Also about file handling(with open) https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: website = action.split()[1].strip()
This line will split the input into a list.
For example,
access google will become ['acess','google']
Then I stored the website name google which is on index 1 and removed the spaces(if extra spaces are there)
So in website variable I will have 'google'

Comment: re.findall(f'{website}\s+(.*?)\n',data,re.S)
This line searchs for the pattern from website name to \n(new line).
So it will get the username and password.
(.*?) captures the data between the website and the new line.
re.S is used when we search for patterns in a multiline string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you a more conceptual answer than code, because this is a more long term type of deal.

What you're going to want to do is use [json files](https://realpython.com/python-json/) and [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) to store your data so you can search by keys (see the dictionaries link).

Once you've done that you're going to want to wrap everything in a while loop inside a def that gets user input like so:

```
def get_input():
    permitted_actions = ['new', 'access', 'exit']
    while True:
        action = input("What do you want to do? Valid actions: new, access or type EXIT to end the program.").strip().lower()
        if action not in permitted_actions:
            print(f"{action} is not a valid action!")
        elif action == 'new':
            #call another function to do stuff here
        elif action == 'access':
            #call another function to do stuff here
        elif action == 'exit':
            print("Shutting down...")
            break
```

I would *highly* recommend against creating your own actual vault for a password manager until you're much more experienced if you actually intend to use this, otherwise feed it fake passwords and whatnot and learn.

Now when you're adding website data you'll read your dictionary (see the dictionary link) and get the key associated with said website if it exists and then update the info that the user gives.

When you're accessing a website's data you just go to the dictionary (see the dictionary link) and grab the info relating to that website key if it exists.

Remember, you're going to be loading that dictionary from a json file (see the json link).

If you were to make this program an actual program someone would use you'd use a proper database of some sort (python3 has sqlite support natively) and use a database with encryption and master passwords.

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I would strongly advise that you dont use plain text files a other files that can easily be opened and read for a password manager. Like Treatybreaker said you should use a databse or similar to do this. Using a databse like sqlite3 will allow you to save your passwords secuerly and you can create a table to store the information and easily access it without having to load a dictionary and convert it

Answer (score 0):

You can save the values as a dictionary with a list as the username and password then use literal_eval to convert the string dict into a dict and access the username and password as well as storing other websites with its own usernames and passwords.

```
website = 'google'
username,password = 'potato', 'potato'

filename = "yourfilehere"

with open(filename, w) as f:
    f.write(str({website: [username,password]}))
    #This will save your data as a string dictionary will the data above

#then read the file, get the dictionary and convert it then use its values
from ast import literal_eval
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

data = literal_eval(data)
#Then search dictionary for website
found = data.get(website)
#Then if it was successful get the username and password
username = found[0]
password = found[1]
```

As long as you only have the dictionary created as a string in the file you are reading you can use this ethod to save as many website with the allocated username and password saved with it.

You can add a input() into the code to check which site the user wants the username and password for and then search for it in your dictionary.

```
search = input("Enter the website: ")
try:
    found = data.get(search)
    #add code here to get username and password
except:
    print("failed to find a website matching: %s" % search")
```